# HTML Reference to Image in RAM/Memory

Tags: c#, html, image, memory, reference

I want to render a html-page with the C#-Webbrowser Form. 
Normally I receive the html file from another application. For simplicity I just read the html page from the hard drive into a stream and then I set the webBrowserControl to this content.
That works in general. But now I want the html file to reference to images in the imageList.
I don't want to save the images to the hard drive. 
Is there any possibilty to reference images in RAM with HTML. 
The common way like

```
<img src="C:\\pic.png"/>
```

is obviously not possible.

Explanation Code

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(src_pathfile); //normally from another application over interface
List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();
imageList.Add(image);

Stream source = File.OpenRead("C:\\Webpage.html");  //from another application
webBrowser.DocumentStream = source;
```

Thank you for your help in advance.
magicbasti

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the image as base-64 and store it in the `<img>` tag itself.  There's some information about it [here](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html).

Comment: That should work. But the problem is that the application keeps the list of images for the whole lifecycle. The application can add and delete images from the list. The html files come/arrive independently from the images and should reference them. so I can't put them together to one file.